# How to parse a picture from a JSON file in table view cell

Tags: json, swift, parsing, uiimageview

I want to parse a  picture from my json file to my SubViewController , but I do not know how to do it. I have tried to do something , but it seems that it is wrong, would you please help me. Here is my JSON file:

```
  {"Name":"Fruit1",
       "Picture":"http://www.starpropertiesindia.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/kochi1.jpg",
        "Description":"red"
        },
```

I want to segue them to SubViewController and I get another error:

Cannot assign value of type NSURL to type UIimage ! in that line:

```
            let ImageView = fruits[indexpath.row].imageURL

            VC .SentData3 = ImageView
```

If that can help you I have created a struct at the beginning:

```
struct Fruit {
    let name : String
    let imageURL : NSURL
    let description : String
}
```

Comment: But I have this problem:
Cannot assign value of type NSURL to type UIimage !

Comment: Of course: an URL is not an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with [parsing JSON](https://www.raywenderlich.com/120442/swift-json-tutorial), but you can try this way.

```
func parseJSON() -> Fruit {
    var json: Array!
    do {
      json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(JSONData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions()) as? Array
    } catch {
      print(error)
    }

    guard let item = json[0] as? [String: AnyObject],
          let name = item["Name"] as? String,
          let pictureString = item["Picture"] as? String,
          let description = item["Description"] as? String else {
      return  
    }

    return Fruit(name, imageURL: NSURL(string: pictureString), description: description)
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    let myFruit = parseJSON()

    if segue.identifier == "yourSegueIdentifier" {
        if let vc =  segue.destinationViewController as? SubViewController { 
           let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: myFruit.imageURL!)
           vc.imageView.image = UIImage(data: data!)
        }
    }
}
```